# Getting gstreamer to produce out of usb-audio

Tags: alsa, gstreamer, usb-audio

I cannot get gstreamer on raspbian (buster) to play through a
usb-audio device, despite other players (vlc, aplay) being able to do
so.  but i need gstreamer because of its API access, for `mpd` players
like `gmpc`.

this post is related to many others i've found (listed below), but
i've exhausted the resources mentioned there, so i and want to report
on experiments i've done, still without success.

Following [suggestions here](https://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-a-raspberry-pi)  i find:

- lsusb

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:558c SanDisk Corp. 
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  ```
- aplay -l

  ```
  **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
  card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  ```
- cat /proc/asound/modules

  ```
  0 snd_bcm2835
  1 snd_usb_audio
  ```
- cat /proc/asound/cards

  ```
  0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                       bcm2835 ALSA
  1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                       USB PnP Sound Device at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, full speed
  ```

and so i've editted my `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` to look like:

```
    defaults.ctl.card 1 # 0
    defaults.pcm.card 1 # 0
```

The image below captures my understanding of the various alternative
paths from sound files to audio output.

[image]

(i see mentions of pulseaudio around others; does it impact gstreamer?
should i include it in the picture?)

i've tried 7 different experiments, and also varied touchscreen
vs. HDMI display options.   Result summary:

[image]

the `vlc` experiments show that it is able to get to usb-audio in both
cases.  `aplay` with the touchscreen is also able to send sound to
usb-audio.  (my current guess is that aplay is missing some `mp3` codec
and barfing out noise?)

clearly there are lower-level (kernel? raspbian?) resource paths that
i don't know about.   how can i make gstreamer consume whatever
resource it is that `vlc` and `aplay are able to use to get to usb-audio?

### resources

- [USB audio device is displayed as default, but is not](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96170/usb-audio-device-is-displayed-as-default-but-is-not)
- [How can I use an external USB sound-card and set it as default?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/how-can-i-use-an-external-usb-sound-card-and-set-it-as-default)
- https://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-a-raspberry-pi--mac-55876
- https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2019/06/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-the-raspberry-pi/
- [gstreamer via python](http://brettviren.github.io/pygst-tutorial-org/pygst-tutorial.html)

Comment: I'm having similar issues using a USB sound card on Raspberry Pi OS (Buster).   It doesn't seem to matter what I do, gst-launch-1.0 hangs.